# which file does wordpress add the import statement for custom.css

Tags: css, wordpress

I cannot seem to find the answer. I want to know which file wordpress adds the import statement for the `custom.css`.

I want to do this so that i can import another css file right after it.

I am not using any css plugins.

Comment: functions.php file add css and js

Answer (score 0):

Using @import in WordPress for adding custom CSS is no longer the best practice, yet you can do it with that method. The best practice is using the function `wp_enqueue_style()` in functions.php.

```
wp_enqueue_style ('theme-style', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/style.css');
wp_enqueue_style ('my-style', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/custom.css', array('theme-style'));
```